# Canvas.Left vs Canvas.Right

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

- What is the difference between `Canvas.Right` and `Canvas.Left` similarly `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Bottom`
- It is really painful when i align the controls with `Canvas.Right` and when i try to align in the Design mode it adds the `Canvas.Left`, how to prevent auto adding `Canvas.Left` property to a control while aligning it, as I already defined the `Canvas.Right` to it why it doesn't update the same property. Its really irritating when we want to do animation on controls, it reverses the direction of animation

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this is don't use the visual drag&drop designer. It will do it's best but it cannot read your mind. If you know what you want, you are faster doing XAML directly, than visually designing it and then manually doing XAML optimization anyway.

Comment: Exactly, learning how to use layouts properly (Grid, StackPanel etc) is probably the way to go.

Comment: The drag and drop shouldn't try to do anything clever if you ask me. That behaviour makes a mess of a lot of trivial tasks.

Answer (score 3):

`Canvas.Left` is the distance between left side of control and left side of `Canvas` and `Canvas.Right` is the distance of the right side from the right and analogically it's the same with `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Bottom`. You can read about it in [`Canvas` attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas_attachedproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The designer is not particularly intelligent or helpful in this case. The only way is to do it manually in XAML